# Why don't we have a specific database only for authentication and another one for the rest?

Tags: php, sql, web

I wanted to know why isn't easier and more secure to have one database service, dedicated only to user authentication (withholding usernames and passwords) which would be well secured (inputs well sanitized etc.)

And another database service for all the other data in the website which would be possibly less secured and available for serving web content.

Wouldn't it be a good way to prevent a lot of the SQL injections happening these days?

Comment: Why secure your app if the data doesn't have to be secure ?

Comment: You say this is a noob question, but this is exactly the kind of thinking that allows most significant breaches to occur. A company will obsessively monitor and secure a certain system. Meanwhile, some unpatched, nearly-forgotten, web-accessible service sits neglected until observant penetrator injects/escalates/roots the box and easily accesses "super secure" db from the inside.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need to look deeper into your RDBMS protection layers to get a better picture why they are better in the same instance.

Let's take for example your MySQL database:

- an instance is made out of 3 + databases (mysql, information_schema, and all others you create).
- so you already have a separate database repo that is handling the auth + user + pass - and that is your MySQL database.

There are ways to develop applications that are hacker free - when working with MySQL most of the coders use open SQL code (inline SQL) - and this is the problem - hackers will take advantage of this! To fix this use stored procedures (encapsulated).

Inside database privileges are a problem as well - lazy developers or stupid DBA will give extra rights for application users. Your idea is redundant from many points of view. More instances will cost you more money, more resources, etc.

Comment: I understand that there different databases in one DBMS... but what I'm concerned about is that if an sql injection is possible because some lazy developer, who isn't necessarely me, didn't use prepared statements, than the attacker automatically has access to information_schema, passwords or password hashes etc. And if there would be two services than it could be some how more secure... but there's probably a lot of design problems in this idea that I didn't yet see.

Comment: For this you have DBA, he will have to manage the database access the right way. There are some basic rules like no password in text, limit for failed login's, ip address, etc...

Comment: I see... thanks... the thing that I'm worried about is that if there is an injection... once the attacker manages to exploit the injection, than there is no failed logins, the ip address is connecting to the database is "localhost" and password hashes are often crackable.

Comment: i agree with you, that is why we need ot monitor our databases constantly, but more important make sure you know  what is you regular database/application "state" in order for you catch "out of state" situations. You get my point !

Comment: when monitoring you need some key point(values) that will alert you once you get t much I/O coming form one session, or when you get to many accesses from a single point, of when you get inline sql to alter your data without any where predicates !!(nobody truncates tables in a production site) - these is constant admin job! and if any developer makes a mistake - is still the dba/admin fault !

Answer (score 1):

You seem to miss two points :

- the rest of your data also should be secure (or else there's no point in securing the application)
- you **don't** store passwords. Never. You only store a hash built from the password, the username (optionally) and a record specific salt. So it's not so important to secure that base, it only is done to prevent impersonation

As there's no reason to secure in a greater manner that part of the DB, just ensure the whole is correctly secured, it's so much easier to manage one DB than two TB. Trying to keep different types of data in different RDBMS and to maintain their coherency is a nightmare.

Lastly, note that this shouldn't change anything regarding to mysql injections. Just don't allow those injections by using prepared statements.

Comment: How to securely hash passwords: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords

Comment: @Darsstar Thanks, I was wondering what link to provide to give OP a good overview of the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is a difference between sanitizing inputs and protecting passwords. SQL injection can happen in any query, and allows someone not only to steal, but also to destroy data. This should be prevented at all times.

Regarding usernames and passwords, there are *additional* measures to take. For one, don't store passwords at all, but always store hashed versions, hashed with a *salt*. Furthermore, you might put the authentication in a different database or even some authentication service if you like, but like I said, that's extra.

Of course, if you got a big bunch of data that is read-only from a website perspective, you might store that in a different database, or at least make the website connect using a database user that doesn't have any rights to modify the data. That way, the data is better protected against destruction, because errors on the website, SQL injection and even leaking of the username and password will not lead to destruction of the data. But this also goes for both the user credentials as the 'less important' data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough quesiton. Indeed you can have two databases one for sensible data, the other for "furnishing".

Let's put it this way: even if you use a database only for "furnishing", what happens if that database get hacked ? Will your users have to see "THIS SITE WAS HACKED" in the  section or...? :)

EDIT: What is protection? Protection is when you buy a coffee and you don't want your friend or someone to drink it. Then what if you buy a coffee and a muffin. Would you protect only one ? Would you protect both ? Which one is more important for you ? If you're like me and most people you would say both. What you made me understand by commening is that muffin (users) is more important than something else (furnishing).

Why would you need protection, if you don't care about the coffee ? Probably because you don't really value coffee enough to protect it. Then let me say this: the money you used to buy your coffee were worth when they were still money, but now they're coffee, what's changed apart from their shape ? Nothing.

Now let's get back to our case: if you have a simple database which contains only "furnishing" texts like "TITLE", "DESCRIPTION" etc. Having them lost isn't bad ? Won't you have to go there and fix them ? Won't you have to WORK to get everything pretty ?

Not to speak that most vulnerabilities related to a database might get pretty worse than just losing only ONE database. Having a sql injection issue might get all database destroyed, that's the danger you're trying to avoid. So, it's almost pointless to try to secure a database more than another. Try to secure everything instead, you'll be sure that everywhere you go, nothing could happen.
So you fear a special inmate, and you secure him A LOT, and trascurate that old cell. You look away, the inmate in the old cell is now out of his cell! And worse, he freed the special inmate (and everyone else). That's the kind of security hole a sql injection imply.

Comment: yes data furnished to the user could potentially be compromised but I consider it's less damaging than defacing the website AND stealing authentification credentials

Comment: @blogresponder : Well, saying "deface", is not really different from saying "<h1>THIS SITE WAS HACKED</h1>". So let's skip to another concept: continue in the edit.